# TypeError - string indices must be integers, not str

Tags: python, typeerror

I got the following output when I printed data retrieved from **MongoDB**:

```
[{"username": "ashish.mishra", "password": "hxMNwFOa", "frequency": "Daily", "name": "Ashish Mishra", "email": "ashish@mail.com"}]
```

Here's how I retrieved it:

```
user = db.UserData.find()
user = dumps(user)
print user //this is the printed version above
```

I want to access each of the keys. I tried:

```
print user['username']
```

and

```
print user[0]['username']
```

It gave me the **error:**

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str
```

I know there are a lot of threads on these, but I haven't been successful with them so far. Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Could not reproduce.

Comment: [Works on my machine](http://ideone.com/XjWdUN)

Comment: Are you sure the contents of `user` is a dictionary and not a string?

Comment: what is the output of `print type(user)` and `for el in user: print type(el)`?

Comment: modified the question guys, please have a look

Comment: Could you do `print type(user)`, please?

Comment: Why do you call `dumps`? It returns a string, which leads to your error.

Comment: dumps is from the bson_util library. The type is string.

Comment: If you are actually using `dumps(user)` then you have a string

Comment: Ok then what should I use?

Comment: If you know it's a string, why are you treating it like a `list` that contains a `dict`?

Comment: Just use `db.UserData.find()`, you can iterate over the find object, `for doc in db.UserData.find():`

Comment: I didnt know that, I got know when I used 'type' as suggested

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to convert string to dictionary first, like this:

```
import json

# initialize user here
user_dict = json.loads(user)
print user_dict[0]['username']
```

Comment: It's rather silly to convert an object to JSON with `dumps` and then back to an object with `loads`. Just use the original object.

Comment: @interjay Yeah, I completely agree. Can you make it an answer? It makes much more sense

Comment: I won't post an answer because I haven't used mongoDB and I don't know what `find()` returns or what the recommended way to use it is. Padraic Cunningham suggests iterating over it in a comment above.

Answer (score -4):

You have a dictionary object inside a list object.

The issue here is that Python assumes you want to retrieve an item from the list using a supplied index number.

Remove the brackets from the users variable and your dictionary will be a dictionary.

```
users = {"username": "ashish.mishra", "password": "hxMNwFOa", "frequency": "Daily", "name": "Ashish Mishra", "email": "ashish@mail.com"}
print user['username']
```

Comment: They cannot just "remove the brackets" the list of dictionaries comes from an external source, namely a JSON file it seems

Comment: I guess i didn't read that part. Thanks for the catch. alexo_o's response above is the best approach.